# CABasicAnimation seemingly performing two animations

Tags: swift, xcode6, cabasicanimation

The small scale animation works as expected but the scale animation to return to the normal size does something weird; it does the animation to the normal scale right but then it does the same animation again but a lot faster.

Here is my code:

```
func changeState(sender:UIButton){
        println(insideSolidLayer.animationKeys())
        if (shouldAnimate){
            shouldAnimate = false
            if (on){
                animateSolidAway()
            }else{
                animateSolidIn()
            }
            on = !on
        }
    }

    func animateSolidAway(){
        insideSolidLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
        let scaleAnimate:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimate.fromValue = 1
        scaleAnimate.toValue = 0
        scaleAnimate.duration = 0.2;
        scaleAnimate.delegate = self
        scaleAnimate.removedOnCompletion = false
        scaleAnimate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
        insideSolidLayer.addAnimation(scaleAnimate, forKey: "scaleSmallAnimation")

    }

    func animateSolidIn(){
        insideSolidLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 0)
        let scaleAnimate:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimate.fromValue = 0
        scaleAnimate.toValue = 1
        scaleAnimate.duration = 3;
        scaleAnimate.delegate = self
        scaleAnimate.removedOnCompletion = false
        scaleAnimate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        insideSolidLayer.addAnimation(scaleAnimate, forKey: "scaleNormalAnimation")
    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
        if(anim.isKindOfClass(CABasicAnimation)){
            if (insideSolidLayer != nil && insideSolidLayer.animationKeys() != nil && insideSolidLayer.animationKeys().count > 0){
                if contains(insideSolidLayer.animationKeys() as [String], "scaleSmallAnimation"){
                    if (anim == insideSolidLayer.animationForKey("scaleSmallAnimation")){
                        println("-animationDidStop- -scaleSmallAnimation-")
                        insideSolidLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 0)
                        shouldAnimate = true
                    }
                }

                if contains(insideSolidLayer.animationKeys() as [String], "scaleNormalAnimation"){
                    if (anim == insideSolidLayer.animationForKey("scaleNormalAnimation")){
                        println("-animationDidStop- -scaleNormalAnimation-")
                        insideSolidLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
                        shouldAnimate = true

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
func animateSolidAway(){

        let scaleAnimate:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimate.fromValue = 1
        scaleAnimate.toValue = 0
        scaleAnimate.duration = 0
        scaleAnimate.delegate = self
        scaleAnimate.removedOnCompletion = false
        scaleAnimate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
        insideSolidLayer.addAnimation(scaleAnimate, forKey: "scaleSmallAnimation")


    }

    func animateSolidIn(){
        insideSolidLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
        let scaleAnimate:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimate.fromValue = 0
        scaleAnimate.toValue = 1
        scaleAnimate.duration = 0
        scaleAnimate.delegate = self
        scaleAnimate.removedOnCompletion = false
        scaleAnimate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        insideSolidLayer.addAnimation(scaleAnimate, forKey: "scaleNormalAnimation")
    }
```